# How to do an action after an AJAX call is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement, callback

I try to call a function at different place. That why i return true or false.
Problem i got is before hasCreditCard has time to do is call, that go directly to the else...

```
if (hasCreditCard($('#memberId').val())) {
  ...
}
else{
  ...
}

function hasCreditCard(memberId) {
    var url = getHostName() + "/members/" + memberId + "/creditcard";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "head",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + $.cookie('authorization')
        },
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 200) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: put your code in `ajax success`` function which you want to execute in `if` condition, and in `ajax error` function put your code which you want to execute in else part

Comment: you can try  async: false attribute of ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an AJAX call is `asynchronous` and your `if-statement` doesn't wait the end of the call.

Two solutions:

**`#1`:** You can pass a callback to the function and call this callback in your success/error handler:

```
getCreditCard($('#memberId').val(), function (hasCreditCard) {
  if (hasCreditCard) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
})

function getCreditCard(memberId, nextStep) {
  ...
  jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
      if (jqXHR.status == 200) {
        nextStep(true)
        return
      }
      nextStep(false)
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
      nextStep(false)
    }
  })
}
```

**`#2`:** You can create another global function and call this function in your success/error handler:

```
getCreditCard($('#memberId').val())

function getCreditCard(memberId) {
  ...
  jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
      if (jqXHR.status == 200) {
        nextStep(true)
        return
      }
      nextStep(false)
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
      nextStep(false)
    }
  })
}

function nextStep(hasCreditCard) {
  if (hasCreditCard) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```